# Dipping a Cube in oil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, frequency

Consider our favorite 1.8 kg cube of side .1 m hanging on a string.  As usual, I pluck the string with the cube hanging in air and hear a tone of 100 Hz.  To commemorate my new house, I now put the cube in a big vat of olive oil and pluck the string again.  Now i hear a frequency of 50 Hz.  What is the density of the olive oil?

I figure that with this question, that the cube holds the string taut.  Thus I assume I can use
$$y(x,t) = y_msin(km - \omega t)$$
$$\omega =2 \pi * f$$
I also assume that dipping the system in oil will change $k$.  I'm just not sure how to calculate that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency of a plucked string goes like $\sqrt{T/\rho}$, where T is the tension in the string and $\rho$ is the linear mass density. The frequency has gone down by a factor 2, so the tension, hence the not-floating cube’s weight is only 1/4 of what it was.

From that, we deduce that the oil’s density is 3/4 that of the block.

And from that, you get that it’s about 1.35. But that seems high for oil, which should be less than 1

Comment: While that seems high, I know that answer to be correct.

Thank you for the excellent explanation as to why.